# How to abort asynchronous method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, listbox

I get data from asynchronous method.  E.g i have two ListBox .When selection changed event occuered in 1st listbox, it sends request to asynchronous  method, and gets 2nd listbox's items source. If before this async method completed, change of selection in first ListBox, method raises exception.How to abort previus async call before it is completed?

Comment: Show us the EventHandler's code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will need some work.
Easiest way at the moment might be the Rx-Framework (Reactiveextensions).
Have a look at this [site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609)

If you don't want to go this road (need some learning), than you have to provide some mechanism to stop running async. requests. You can do this with [System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.aspx) or with a System.Threading.ManualResetEvent. Both can be used to flag a cancellation to a running task/thread, but the first might be clearer.

Most async. request can be called with a [CancellationToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.aspx) (just use the [.Token-Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.token.aspx) of the source) as far as I know. If not you can use your own Thread and check with [ThrowIfCancellationRequested](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested.aspx).

Or you can check on your EndAsync-Handler if the request should be cancelled (e.g.not processed),...

Comment: Method is in web service i only send parametres and callback method

Comment: then remember the value you asked and check in the callback if that has changed - if yes ignore the data you got - if you can give some kind of userinfo (a object - it's often the case) to the call you can give this info to the call if you can't read it from the response

Comment: I resolved problem .used bool isLoadingResourcesFinished.When i attemp to call method i call if (isLoadingResourcesFinished) {..isLoadingResourcesFinished=false}.and in callback method i give true to this.and it works

Comment: yes this might work but then the user cannot change his seletion while the answer is on it's way. Better don't stop this and just check if you got the right anwer back - but do as you like or your specs tells you to :)